# Reverse Ajax implementation using php

Tags: php, reverse-ajax

I am looking to implement reverse ajax in my application which is using PHP and jquery. I have googled a bit about it and found XAJA but that seems to be a paid application. Is there an open source application available for the same or has someone implemented it?

Some pointers or hints would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean something like Comet, or HTML5-style websockets?

Comment: I have read about Comet but that needs intensive support from server side and as I have found, it does not perform well with apache server.

Comment: HTML5-style websockets seems to be interesting but needs support from browsers. As per the document currently only safari and chrome support it?

Answer (score 1):

I know of two types of reverse AJAX:
1- Polling
2- Pushing

I think polling is rather easier to implement, you just have your javascript make a regular request to the server every time interval, and when the server have some data for it it will respond. Its like a ping and some call it heartbeat, but its the very obvious solution for this problem. However it may easily overload the server.

**EDIT** Simple polling Example code:
Server-Side:

```
<?php
//pong.php php isn't my main thing but tried my best!
$obj = new WhatsNew();
$out = "";
if ($obj->getGotNew()){
    $types = new array();
    foreach ($obj->newStuff() as $type)
        {
            $new = array('type' => $type);
            $types[] = $new;
        }

    $out = json_encode($types);
}
else{
    $out = json_encode(array('nothingNew' => true));
}
```

Client-Side:

```
function ping(){
    $.ajax(
        {

            url : "pong.php",
            success : function (data){
                data = JSON.parse(data),
                if (data['nothingNew'])
                    return;
                for(var i in data){
                    var type = data[i]['type'];
                    if (type && incomingDataHandlers[type]){
                        incomingDataHandlers[type]();
                    }
                }


        });
}
incomingDataHandlers = {
    comments: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "getComments.php",
            method: "GET",
            data: getNewCommentRequsetData() // pass data to the server;
            success : function (data){
                //do something with your new comments
            }
        });
    },
    message: function (){
        $.ajax({
            url: "getMessages.php",
            method: "GET",
            data: getNewMessageRequestData() // pass data to the server;
            success : function (data){
                //do something with your new messages
            }
        });
    }
}
$(docment).ready(function () {
    setInterval(ping, 1000);
})
```

Comment: Thanks amjad, I know about these types. I am looking for some hint or pointers on how it can be implemented actually.

Comment: I have seen your code but that does not seem to be an example of polling or pushing. It a simple example of ajax request repeated after a fixed interval.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for what they call "long poll" - I did a "long poll php" and I got this thread on stack overflow:

[How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

Comment: thanks knubo, looks good. However, I have got another good link. Check this http://www.ape-project.org/home.html may be it helps you in future.

Comment: I will surely try your solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could websockets in conjuction with "flash" websockets because almost all browser have flash on board(average around 96%? => http://www.statowl.com/flash.php) => https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js. You could use this together with http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/. Still I am wondering if the performance is going to be any good. If it all possible I would use node.js to do reverse ajax. http://socket.io is a really cool project to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/) ?

Its a push based real-time data streaming technology over a single low volume ajax connection.  The concept is useful, you may be able to replicate the same thing with your server-side implementation