# How to apply reverse ajax in my php page to reload my listed items?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I want to use reverse ajax in my php page to reload updated data on server. Another issue is that i need only those data which are recently added or updated to database, how can i filter such data in reverse ajax.

Please help me to reverse ajax using jquery in context of my problem  with example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse Ajax implementation using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568524/reverse-ajax-implementation-using-php)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please give example

Comment: Basic examples  http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery and here https://gist.github.com/jasdeepkhalsa/4353139

Comment: My tab application updates online database, so i need to reflect its effect to live website without reload. I think above link will guide me to solution. Thanks bob.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this thread:

[How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

I think there is no way to do reverse ajax without extra software on serverside.
If you don't want to use something like comet you have to check with ajax every 1 or 2 minutes for updates and this will have a big impact on your scalability.