# How i can get notification when database update from another browser / computer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[image]
**My Question **
while chatting on Facebook , when u receive a message from someone, you get a notification showing number of new messages with red background.
so my question is how we can do so that we recieve a notification when database is changed from another computer.
I done it with the following codes and it work well but it seem harmful for processor as it run mysql query each second.

the following jquery code

```
$(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'incs/check_new_msg.php' ,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            $('#orders').html(data);
                        },

                    });
                }, 1000);
            });
```

in check__new_msg.php i use query
select count(id) from inbox where status = '1' 
then i echo its result

Comment: Do you really need it to be refreshed every second?

Comment: no sir , but may be refreshed each second or may be refreshed after 10 - 15 minutes depend on time when client request

Comment: Please post your jQuery code showing how you implemented your timer. A one second interval  typically does not cause any performance issues.

Comment: @Sumurai8 .. I edited my question and hope now it will be understandable for you please check it . thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks. This is much better readable.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for concept of **reverse ajax**.

Here is one answer given to implement it: [Reverse Ajax implementation using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568524/reverse-ajax-implementation-using-php)

Comment: thanks sir. let me check it

Comment: There are several ways of going about this, as this other thread details.  Websockets is a popular one (keeps an open connection between the browser and the server)  but must be configured on the server.

Comment: sir i already done it with ajax request and js timeinterval , but it heatup processor by running query each second

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP wants to make normal client --> server ajax requests ... and not the reverse.